# How to avoid printing a newline when seq completes?

Tags: gnu, seq

To create a column header, looking like:

```
1234567890123456789
```

I (am trying to) use seq and echo:

```
seq -s '' 1 9 ; echo -n 0; seq -s '' 1 9
```

However, seq outputs a newline after each run. How can I avoid that?

Comment: would you care to elaborate why you can't just `echo 1234567890123456789`? and why you need just 19 columns? and why the `echo -n 0; seq -s '' 1 9` instead of `seq -s '' 0 9`?

Comment: @pizdelect: Q1 & 2: I'm looking for an expandable method that might be put in a scripts; Q3: Because I don't want a leading 0.

Comment: Q1 & Q2. what do you want to expand it to? I explained in my answer how to make a header as wide as the terminal, **without** writing the numbers byte by byte. And that's easy to adapt to eg. a header like `abcdeabcde...`. Q3. the two commands from my comment are equivalent.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you just want to print `1234567890123456789`, you can do it with:

```
$ printf "%s" $(seq 1 9) $(seq 0 9)
1234567890123456789$
```

That won't have a trailing newline at all though, so maybe you prefer:

```
$ printf "%s" $(seq 1 9) $(seq 0 9) $'\n'
1234567890123456789
$
```

A few simpler choices if you don't *need* to use `seq`:

```
$ perl -le 'print 1..9,0,1..9'
1234567890123456789
$ printf "%s" {1..9} {0..9} $'\n'
1234567890123456789
```

Since you mentioned portability, I recommend you use the `perl` approach, or if you are likely to encounter systems without `perl`, and yet need the same command to run in shells including `bash`, `sh`, `dash`, `tcsh` etc, try [Kamil's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492327/22222).

Comment: Thanks. How portable is that? It worked under Bash. Under tcsh I got an "Illegal variable name" error. Under sh, the '\n' was displayed.

Comment: @GreenMatt ah, that depends. For extreme portability, you may as well just use the `perl` one which is shell-agnostic. The `printf "%s" $(seq 1 9) $(seq 0 9)` will work in any POSIX shell, including `sh` and `dash`, but the `printf "%s" $(seq 1 9) $(seq 0 9) $'\n'` will fail in `dash`. Note that it does work in `sh` (or at least in `bash` running as `sh`, so in POSIX mode), I assume you're running Ubuntu or a simmilar system whose `sh` is actually `dash`. `tcsh` is a strange one and not even trying to be POSIX so don't expect any of the shell-based approaches to work there.

Comment: @GreenMatt of course, if you need portability, you should also [avoid using `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22222).

Comment: Perl? <shudder>

Comment: @GreenMatt lol. Say what you like about Perl, you just can't beat it for text manipulation and it is extremely portable.

Comment: To be tcsh compatible: `printf "%s\n" "\`\seq 1 9; seq 0 9\`"`

Comment: `printf "%b" $(seq 1 9) $(seq 0 9) '\n'` should work in dash ([`%b` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/printf.html) if I didn't misread)

Comment: @ilkkachu it's the ansi escape (`$'\n'`) that doesn't work, and the `'\n'` just prints a literal `\n`, I think. I'm on mobile now so I can't check though.

Comment: @terdon `printf %b` processes the escapes within `printf`, so `$'..'` isn't needed. `printf %s` of course doesn't do that.

Comment: @GreenMatt, tcsh isn't a POSIX-family shell, so it can't be reasonably expected to be compatible with... well, anything else that isn't in the (small, and [deeply frowned-upon](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)) csh family.

Comment: There are 2 things that don't work in the example with tcsh: 1. the `$()` form of command substitution, 2. the ANSI string expansion.
@ilkkachu: "%b" does expand substituted newlines, but you can also include it in the format string itself.

Comment: @Larry, not with that `printf` structure you can't, the format string gets repeated for each argument, but we only want one newline.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Yes, but you can have both `seq` commands in a single argument, like in my example.
Except for the backslash before the first `seq`, which is just stupid, I left it in somehow.

Comment: @Larry, mm, the [command you posted as a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492315/how-to-avoid-printing-a-newline-when-seq-completes/492319?noredirect=1#comment903815_492319) prints one digit per line. But I'm starting to think you should post that as an answer of your own if you want to refine or discuss it further.

Comment: @ilkkachu You are right. My bad, I actually tested the "%b" variant and didn't know literal newlines will be interpreted differently between "%s" and "%b".
"%b" it is.

Comment: `perl -le 'print 1..9,0,1..9'` is nice - single process, instead of two as in `printf` and `seq` in command substitution

Answer (score 6):

You can remove newlines from any stream with `tr -d '\n'`. In your case

```
(seq -s '' 1 9 ; echo -n 0; seq -s '' 1 9) | tr -d '\n'
```

While other answers may concentrate on modifying your original approach, this is the way that should just remove newline characters regardless of what is before `|`.

Comment: Nice. This also has the benefit of being portable to most (all?) shells. I think the OP wants the final newline, so another option might be `( seq -s '' 1 9 ; echo -n 0 ; seq -s '' 1 9 ) | tr -d '\n' ; printf "\n"`.

Comment: Ah yes, I never think of `tr`.

Comment: +1. Also, worth saying that BSD version of `seq` does treat `-s ''` more fully than GNU's — no newline is printed even when it exits (they q-n wouldn't arise at all there)

Comment: My take on this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492380/6622

Answer (score 5):

I assume you don't want just that particular string, but strings of incrementing digits with variable lengths. For that, it may be useful to be able to change the width by changing one number, instead of having to build it from multiple calls to `seq`.

In Bash, you could use something like this (for a 19-long sequence):

```
for ((i=1; i <= 19; i++)); do printf "%d" "$(( i % 10 ))"; done; echo
```

This should work in a standard shell (and works in at least dash and busybox, anyway):

```
i=1; while [ "$i" -le 19 ]; do printf "%d" "$(( i % 10 ))"; i=$((i+1)); done; echo
```

Comment: +1: The latter approach looks like everything it needs should be guaranteed to be available in any POSIX-y shell to me.

Answer (score 4):

Consider also:

```
printf '%d' $(seq -w 1 1 99 | cut -c2)
```

We generate the numbers 01..99, zero-padded (`-w`), then strip off the tens-place. Those ones-place numbers are then sent to `printf` to be printed individually.

To get your desired output, use `19` instead:

```
$ printf '%d' $(seq -w 1 1 19 | cut -c2)
1234567890123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

[When using `tr`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492327/6622) to get rid of trailing new-line it's worth realising that it deletes *all* occurrences of the characters given in its `-d` option. Thus you can get it a bit more slim:

```
(seq 1 9; echo 0; seq 1 9) | tr -d '\n'
```

— even `echo` doesn't need to have `-n` anymore.

And for completeness sake: BSD's version of `seq` when `-s ''` specified doesn't produce new-line on its exit.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the trailing newline, just use a command execution:

```
 $ echo "test$(seq -s '' 9)no-newline"
 test12345679no-newline
```

Or capture it in a variable:

```
 $ var=$(seq -s '' 9); echo "${var}0${var}"
 1234567890123456789
```

Or also:

```
 $ printf '%s' {{0..9},0,{0..9}}; echo
 1234567890123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you don't just:

```
echo 1234567890123456789
```

And what's the point of printing just 19 columns instead of 20?

If you want it repeated (by default: for the whole width of the terminal)

```
chdr(){ c=${1:-$COLUMNS}; while [ "$c" -gt 0 ]; do printf '%.*s' "$c" 1234567890; c=$((c-10)); done; echo; }
chdr 17
12345678901234567
chdr
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

Of course, that won't work in `csh` (huh).

FYI: `seq` isn't portable (there's `jot` on *BSD, but it's quite different).